# Name of this equational theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, universal-algebra

Consider the (single-sorted) algebraic theory with one binary operation symbol $\ast$ and the following single axiom: $$(x_1 \ast x_2) \ast (x_3 \ast x) = x.$$ One possible model for this theory comes from $\mathbb{Z}$, where $m \ast n := -n$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. $\ast$ is interpreted as the twisted projection on $\mathbb{Z}$).

Has this theory been studied before? And more specifically, is anything known about its word problem?

Comment: With $x_1=x_2=y*y$, we obtain $y*(x_3*x)=x$. With $x_3=x=z*z$, we then get $y*z=z*z$, so $x*y=:f(y)$ depends only on $y$. Finally, $f$ is an involution. - On the other hand, any involutory $f$ can be used to defined $*$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That should be an answer I think.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Great, that makes sense.

Comment: Another class (variety) of algebras satisfying (in a very trivial way) that equation is that of the [Right-zero semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup#Right_zero_semigroup).